# Blender pen tablet wheel not working

Tags: shortcut, mouse

the language may be strange using translator. Please understand. If I register the mouse wheel key through the shortcut key of the pen and press it to write, it works only about 1 out of 3 times. If I change it to mouse mode, it works fine, but if I leave it like this, I can't use the pen pressure, and the pen moves around the screen strangely, so I can't use it. Both pen tablets failed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you be able to tell us which pen tablet you're using? Also, are we to assume you're trying to sculpt with it, as you didn't say?

Comment: Which OS? Does your tablet work in other applications?